# Why is my Excel VBA macro crashing?

Tags: vba, excel

So I made a Excel macro and when i try to run it, it keeps crashing. Here it is:

```
result = "fail"

j = 4

Do While result = "fail" Or Cells(2, j) <> " "

        If Cells(2, j).Value >= 15 Then

           result = "pass"


        Else

           j = j + 1

        End If

Loop
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crash"? At what line does it "crash"?

Comment: Infinite loop because incrementing j must be in both cases

Answer (score 1):

Your `Do While` loop `Do While result = "fail" Or Cells(2, j) <> " "` will run if either `result = "fail"` or `Cells(2, j) <> " "`.

I think you meant to exit the loop once you reach an empty cell, or you get `result = "pass"`. So, you need to change your `Or` to `And`:

```
Do While result = "fail" And Cells(2, j) <> " "
```

If you want to exit in case there are only empty space in the cell, add also `Trim`.

```
Do While result = "fail" And Trim(Cells(2, j)) <> ""
```

Answer (score 0):

changed or to and.
the loop needs to stop somewhere, currently it is going into an endless loop.
pls try below code and let me know if this is what you wanted or I have understood your requirement incorrectly.

```
Sub tester()


result = "fail"

j = 4

Do While result = "fail" And Cells(2, j) <> ""
    If Cells(2, j).Value >= 15 Then

       result = "pass"


    Else

       j = j + 1

    End If

Loop
End Sub
```